# How can I push multiple iterations of the same array into a larger array in Angular for use in dynamic number of tabs?

Tags: html, arrays, angular

I am using a for loop to create an array and I then need to push that array into a larger array. I searched around and I have it functioning but the large array just contains 3 undefined objects.

Code for the for loop:

```js
FinalArray: any[] = [];

    this.databaseService.getclass(id, this.selectedSeries, this.selectedTierNbr, this.selectedAmount)
    .subscribe(classresults => this.classresults = classresults,
     error => console.log('ERROR!'),
     // Populate Bank Level Data using onComplete Observable function
     () => { for (const classresult of this.classresults) {
       this.selectedClassId = classresult.Class_ID;
       console.log(this.selectedClassId);
       this.databaseService.getbank(id, this.selectedS, this.selectedTierNbr, this.selectedAmount, this.selectedClassId)
       .subscribe(bankresults => this.bankresults = bankresults);
       this.FinalArray.push(this.bankresults);
       console.log(this.FinalArray);
     }
   }
```

Here is the array export class in the database service:

```js
export class ClassResult {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
  Group_Name: string;
  S_Id: number;
  S_Name: string;
  Class_ID: number;
  S_Class: string;
  Tier_Nbr: number;
  Tier_Name: string;
  Amount: number;
}

export class BankResult {
  Id: number;
  Name: string;
  Group_Name: string;
  S_Id: number;
  S_Name: string;
  Class_ID: number;
  S_Class: string;
  Tier_Nbr: number;
  Tier_Name: string;
  Amount: number;
  Bank_Name: string;
  Bank_Id: number;
}
```

The end goal I am looking for is so that I can reference this data on a dynamically created number of material tabs. Hoping to look like this:

```html
<mat-tab-group>
<mat-tab *ngFor="let classresult of classresults "
label="S Class -  {{classresult._S_Class}}">
<table class ="responstable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>test</th>
                <th>test</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let bankresult of finalarray.bankresults">
        <td>{{bankresult.S_Class}} </td>
        <td>{{bankresult.Tier_Name}} </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

I also tried to accomplish this with switchMap but couldn't get it working.

```js
this.databaseService.getClass(id, this.selectedS, this.selectedTierNbr, this.selectedAmount).pipe(
    switchMap(classresults => {
      const bankrequests = classresults.map(
        classresult => this.databaseService
          .getBank(id, this.selectedS, this.selectedTierNbr, this.selectedAmount, this.selectedClassId)
          .pipe(map(bankresults => {classresult, bankresults}))
         );
         return forkJoin(bankrequests);
         console.log(bankrequests);
    })
  ).subscribe(results => this.results = results);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of asynchronous behavior of observable subscription.

Try this.

```
this.databaseService.getclass(id, this.selectedSeries, this.selectedTierNbr, this.selectedAmount)
.subscribe(
    (classresults) => {
        this.classresults = classresults;
        for (const classresult of this.classresults) {
            this.selectedClassId = classresult.Class_ID;
            console.log(this.selectedClassId);
            this.databaseService.getbank(id, this.selectedS, this.selectedTierNbr, this.selectedAmount, this.selectedClassId)
                .subscribe((bankresults) => {
                    this.bankresults = bankresults;
                    this.FinalArray.push(this.bankresults);
                    console.log(this.FinalArray);
                });
        }
    },
    (error) => {
        console.log('ERROR!')
    });
```

Comment: Thanks! This got the array to work -- the console.log(this.FinalArray); looks right but my HTML page is empty.

Can you take a look at the HTML above and see if you see anything obvious?

Comment: Sure! But for that i require your response.. So i can see whats wrong

Comment: What information do you need? Everything appears to be working (your fix worked for the FinalArray) but the HTML page doesn't display and results in the table. The code is above for the HTML.

Comment: Do. Not. Do. That. Subscribe inside a subscribe is definitely not a good idea. Use a switchMap or mergeMap according to what you want :)

Comment: The only mistake i can see till now is typo. it should be "FinalArray.bankresults" on your "NgFor".

Comment: I am a beginner so did the for loop as it was easy to understand. I had another Stack post and the swithMap/Map was used but I couldn't get working. I will add that code above if you would like to see.

Comment: I had it spelled correctly in my code -- still not displaying data.

Comment: Can you create plunk for it? u can start from here - https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue

Comment: Will the plunk work even though it would have any data? The databaseservice is using a HTTP call to hit a database and return the arrays.

Comment: You can pass the dummy array... and leave subscribe for now as it is working fine now!